# How can I kill a copy operation?

Tags: c#, windows, process, kill

I am supposed to kill a copy operation to a specific folder on some condition.
My thought process is to watch that folder using FileSystemWatcher and as soon as a file is created, I'll look for a "copy operation" and then kill it.

I am unable to find ways to detect if there is a copy operation to that folder and if there is one, how can I kill it?

I tried to look into taskbar to see if there is a process # then I can kill it with process ID. But it did not work. Any other thoughts please?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. If you need to protect a folder then use standard windows mechanisms like ACLs.  It's also not ideal to randomly going around killing other processes to protect a folder.

Comment: FilesystemWatcher only lets you know when files are changed, added, or deleted.  They don't know how or why (from a copy).

Comment: Looking for other processes won't help you either - I could write a program called guesswhatido.exe that copies files - are you going to kill my process?

Comment: You'll need a little robot that jerks the power plug out of the socket.

Comment: If you don't want somebody copying files into a specific folder, set the ACLs to deny creating a new file.

Comment: @RaymondChen That would deny you the opportunity to write a compatibility shim for this application when Windows 8 is released!

Comment: Windows isn't designed to allow you to do what you're asking for.  It is, however, designed so that you almost certainly don't need to.  If you can describe what you're actually trying to achieve, we may be able to provide better advise.